# WinSCP PuTTY key format too new

Tags: putty, ssh-keys, winscp, public-key, private-key

I am trying to connect to my server with WinSCP. I created a key by PuttyGen but when I am trying to connect to it by WinSCP it says that my PuTTY key format too new, [Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BoCA.png). Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Support for the new Putty version is work in progress: https://winscp.net/tracker/1984

Comment: [WinSCP 5.18.5 RC](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php?n=5.18.5), released just now, supports PuTTY 0.75 PPK3 key files already. See https://winscp.net/tracker/1986